# how to make the app work in all version of android?

Tags: android

Hi everyone,i have developed an app like true caller.in that i am just displaying the
    contact number in a toast,tats it.i compiled this in android version 2.2(api 8).
    app is working fine in android 2.3 and 2.3.3 ,but not in 4.0.1 and 4.1.0..what maybe the
    problem..????

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

     <receiver android:name=".CustomBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />     
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>



</application>


this is my logcat error on android emulator api 17

10-28 07:22:28.950: D/CallNotifier(392): RINGING... (new)
10-28 07:22:28.950: D/CallNotifier(392): onNewRingingConnection(): state = RINGING, conn = {  incoming: true state: INCOMING post dial state: NOT_STARTED }
10-28 07:22:28.998: D/CallNotifier(392): SignalInfoTonePlayer.run(toneId = 98)...
10-28 07:22:29.078: D/PhoneNumberUtils(392): System property doesn't provide any emergency numbers. Use embedded logic for determining ones.
10-28 07:22:29.148: D/PhoneStatusBar(664): disable: < expand icons ALERTS* ticker system_info back home recent clock search >
10-28 07:22:29.258: D/AccelerometerListener(392): enable(false)
10-28 07:22:29.328: I/Choreographer(392): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

10-28 07:22:29.648: W/CallNotifier(392): CallerInfo query took too long; look up local fallback cache.
10-28 07:22:29.657: D/CallNotifier(392): Failed to find fallback cache. Use default ringer tone.
10-28 07:22:29.657: W/CallNotifier(392): CallerInfo query took too long; falling back to default ringtone
10-28 07:22:29.808: D/CallNotifier(392): showIncomingCall()...  phone state = RINGING
10-28 07:22:29.867: W/Trace(289): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-28 07:22:29.867: W/Trace(289): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-28 07:22:29.908: W/Trace(405): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-28 07:22:29.918: W/Trace(405): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-28 07:22:29.968: W/Trace(664): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-28 07:22:30.069: W/Trace(664): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-28 07:22:30.219: I/Choreographer(664): Skipped 140 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-28 07:22:30.249: W/Trace(664): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-28 07:22:30.249: W/Trace(664): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-28 07:22:30.308: D/MediaPlayer(392): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
10-28 07:22:30.308: W/Trace(664): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-28 07:22:30.318: W/Trace(664): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-28 07:22:30.369: W/Trace(664): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-28 07:22:30.398: W/Trace(664): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-28 07:22:30.448: W/Trace(664): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-28 07:22:30.448: W/Trace(664): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-28 07:22:30.578: E/MediaPlayerService(40): Couldn't open fd for content://settings/system/ringtone
10-28 07:22:30.578: E/MediaPlayer(392): Unable to to create media player
10-28 07:22:30.609: D/Ringtone(392): Problem opening; delegating to remote player
10-28 07:22:30.739: I/AudioService(289):  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from AudioFocus_For_Phone_Ring_And_Calls
10-28 07:22:30.788: D/AudioHardwareInterface(40): setMode(RINGTONE)
10-28 07:22:31.058: D/MediaPlayer(664): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
10-28 07:22:31.078: E/MediaPlayerService(40): Couldn't open fd for content://settings/system/ringtone
10-28 07:22:31.199: E/MediaPlayer(664): Unable to to create media player
10-28 07:22:31.199: W/Ringtone(664): Remote playback not allowed: java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
10-28 07:22:31.258: D/Ringtone(664): Problem opening; delegating to remote player
10-28 07:22:31.279: W/Ringtone(664): Neither local nor remote playback available
10-28 07:22:31.568: W/Trace(392): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-28 07:22:31.619: W/Trace(392): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-28 07:22:31.968: I/ActivityManager(289): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10840000 cmp=com.android.phone/.InCallScreen} from pid -1
10-28 07:22:31.978: W/Trace(289): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-28 07:22:32.048: W/Trace(289): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-28 07:22:32.228: W/WindowManager(289): Failure taking screenshot for (164x246) to layer 21015
10-28 07:22:32.228: W/Trace(405): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-28 07:22:32.339: W/Trace(392): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-28 07:22:32.369: W/Trace(289): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-28 07:22:32.477: W/Trace(289): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-28 07:22:32.557: W/Trace(392): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-28 07:22:32.598: I/Choreographer(289): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-28 07:22:32.618: W/Trace(392): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-28 07:22:32.677: D/InCallScreen(392): onNewIntent: intent = Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10c40000 cmp=com.android.phone/.InCallScreen }, phone state = RINGING
```

Comment: Is there any error? Post your logcat in if there is.

Comment: What problem you are encountering in 4.0.1 and 4.1.0.

Comment: im not getting any error,,,it is working well in emulator but not in device

Comment: Besides specifying `android:targetSdkVersion="17"` set the  `android:maxSdkVersion="17"`

Comment: @HemantVc why would android:targetSdkVersion="17" make a difference?? I use it and things work fine.. Chella Kumaran check the log cat to find out whats not working and why. also if you knw what piece of code fails look at the methods if they are appropriate for the new api lvels

Comment: android have support library for older versions, use them when you build your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using like this

```
  TelephonyManager manager =(TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
  mPhoneNumber = manager.getLine1Number();
```

and toasting it
This method you are using is the only one part of the SDK to do this, and only works on devices where  number is stored on the SIM card,(Settings->about phone->status->check whether number is visible, if yes, then only number will display)  For all other carriers, you will have to ask user to enter the phone number manually

Comment: No im not using like this,im using only the 1st line you defined but not the second line.

Comment: my friend is having android version 4.0.1 and obviously my contact is there in his mobile but still is not working

Comment: please check my edited question with logcat error,,, really mind freaking..!!